# Defining styles in Android and need to be inheriting from a parent

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I am a little confused about how I should be writing my styles.

I have written some styles and they appear to work great but I am unsure if I should be inheriting from a style.

For example, by default, a text view (for example) has a default style before applying mine?

So I should be inheriting from something else in my style before applying it, i.e. a halo style?

So, for example, I designed the following style

```
<style name="TestMe">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF0000</item>
</style>
```

Which I have applied to a few text views, seems to work great but should I be doing

```
<style name="TestMe" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFF0000</item>
</style>
```

Inheriting from a parent, if so which one?

If I apply a style to my text view and do not inherit, in effect is the text view losing a lot of styles that were predefined on it before applying my style? I know that I have an app theme that inherits from a parent and this is applied in the androidmanifest.xml. So adding a style doesn't override the theme, which in essence is a style?

Or is inheritance on styles only being used when I want to override something?

Comment: You should take a look at the [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html) section of the documentation. It's pretty well explained there.

Comment: Inherit when you want to copy rest of attributes to your style. Without inherited attributes, views will fall back to default values.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So what i am having a problem understanding is, if I assign a style to a textview that doesn't inherit, so it goes back to the default ? What are the defaults...   But if I inherit from android:TextAppearance  which I presume that all textviews would have then i bring along those properties too. ??

Comment: @Martin I post it my answer have to look at it

Answer (score 1):

Be aware of the precedence order of different styling techniques — if you’re trying to style some text and not seeing the results you expect then your changes are likely being overridden by something higher up in this hierarchy:[image]

Here the whole detail regarding text appearance [URL](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d)